# MySQL replace rows

Tags: mysql, insert, replace, one-to-many

I have a bunch of 2 column tables and I'd like to replace all rows referring to a certain id with new rows.

Is there a way to do this in a single query so I don't have to do DELETE -> INSERT? I've read that there is a replace statement but it only inserts or updates, it doesn't remove values right?

I have a page that has 3 checkbox groups - each of these groups correspond to a table. On form submit, I'd like to replace all rows with new rows depending on checkbox post values.

I appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: What's problematic about a DELETE & INSERT that can't be rectified with an UPDATE?

Comment: Perhaps include some sample data?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I have misunderstood your requirement, but why not just use a normal update statement, e.g.

```
update my_table set my_col_1 = "some_value_1", my_col_2 = "some_value_2" where some_id = 1;
```

So you can just choose which columns you want to replace and add that to the list of columns in the set part of the query.

If this doesn't meet your requirement maybe give some more info, for example the SQL you are currently using with the DELETE -> INSERT approach and then we can see if it can be simplified.